# How to remove GRUB from dual boot (Debian and Windows XP)

Tags: windows-xp, debian, grub, multi-boot, grub2

I have a computer witch cannot be boot from CD or USB. I have Debian and Windows XP with dual boot via GRUB. Now I want to uninstall Debian and GRUB and restore the Windows `MBR`.

I can enter boot Debian and Windows OSes, but no boot from CD or USB for recovery. How can I remove GRUb and restore MBR from within Windows XP or Debian?

**NOTE:** I asked this question [before](https://superuser.com/questions/481557/how-to-replace-grub-boot-loader-from-within-windows), but after accepting the answer, I found that Windows XP does not have `fdisk` command. However, I think it is too late to continue the discussion there; thus, I asked this brand new question.

Comment: Honestly the easiest fix is to shell out $10 bucks for an IDE CD-ROM and replace the broken drive. Then just boot into repair mode from an XP install disk.

Comment: @LeeHarrison I agree with you, but I doubt if the whole machine values $10 :D I just want to fix it for a friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recovery console has fixmbr which will do that for you. Found instructions how "Recovery console" can be started without CD. [Repair MBR without CD](http://www.ehow.com/how_6772631_repair-mbr-windows-xp-cd.html)
I cannot test the procedure as I don't have XP anymore.

```
Quick steps:
Run "C:\Windows\i386\winnt32.exe /cmdcons"
Restart and select "Recovery console" during boot-up
Run "fixmbr"
```

Answer (score 1):

Restart the pc, using the installation CD, boot it, then click repair, then choose the command line option. Then type this:

```
bootrec/fixboot
bootrec/fixmbr
```

then download and use EasyBCD to edit boot.